# Keep same footer across mutiple directories

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, footer

I have a footer and that needs to be applied to all the pages in  my website, which is fairly easy. but the thing is these pages are in different directories some time even in sub-directories im my website but I want the same footer in all these pages and wanna keep a consistent url format so that i dont have to fiddle with urls of link present in the footer.

I have looked into  URL rewriting and have tried making the links server controls and handling the url of those links in .cs pages and it works but the solution doesnt seem elegant.

Can someone tell me a way to use a footer(with links) in pages spread across multiple directories such that i can handle the url of the links in consistent format.

Comment: "User Control" is one of the way. Make UC of footer section and use it on all page

Comment: im doing tht currently, footer is actually a UC

Comment: Can't you use `MasterPage` ?

Comment: Can you show some code of footer section. how are you using the links?

Comment: Please show sample of links you are talking about. It is not clear why links would need to change (assuming you have either absolute Urls or path starting from the root like "/Home/Index").